# Theme Issue on WebSphere Portal V8.0.0.1

Tags: themes, websphere-portal

Please need help to resolve an issue of Theme. These are the details:

1) WebSphere Portal V8.0.0.1 CF14
2) Customize Theme created from default Portal theme.
3) The same theme works on Portal V8.0.0.0
4) Getting an error when my Theme is assigned to the page. This is the error in Sys logs when goes to that page:

servlet E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause /themes/html/Default.jsp: com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: com.ibm.wps.resolver.data.exceptions.URIProcessingIOException: EJCBD0021E: The URI [dav:fs-type1/themes/Portal8.0/theme.html] and parameters [['themeURI'=['dav:fs-type1/themes/Portal8.0/theme.html'], 'mime-type'=['text/html']]] could not be processed: [EJCBD0021E: The URI [dav:fs-type1/themes/Portal8.0/nls/theme_en.html] and parameters [['themeURI'=['dav:fs-type1/themes/Portal8.0/theme.html'], 'mime-type'=['text/html']]] could not be processed: [EJCBD0021E: The URI

5) Also, experience an uneven behavior of creating page on to the same Portal instance where my customize theme had been created.

Looking forward for your views. Thanks

Comment: is this the first error you see? usually something happens that causes the item to be unavailable, my guess is that possibly you are running into issues with the security whitelist/blacklist before this error

Comment: Thank you. Specifying the first NullPointerException error and the error below it as mentioned in my question:
Servlet       E com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet handleException EJPEJ0070E: An exception occurred while processing the request.
                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.wps.resourceaggregator.utils.DefaultFilesFinder.getFilePathInfos(DefaultFilesFinder.java:253)
        at com.ibm.wps.resourceaggregator.profile.ProfileHelper.getAllProfilePathInfos(ProfileHelper.java:278)

Comment: did this happen just after the cf application, do you see the webdav existing, I have seen cases where webdav has gotten cleared out and had to be replaced.  Take a look at http://<host>:<port>/wps/mycontenthandler/dav/fs-type1?mime-type=application/zip and use that to extract it from the server